# How to detect whether a third-party python package is available on a fixed python version like python3.4

Tags: python, pip

I am embedding python code in my cpp application to provide python-code-runner service. Recently I encountered a problem when I really need to downgrade my python version from 3.8.10 to 3.4.4, so that my application can fit on windows xp.

I used to provided some automatically-installed python 3rd-party packages for my customers to use. Now, as the downgrade of python version, I have to downgrade the 3rd-party packages' version to let my app function fine.

The problem is that I have no idea how to determine whether a 3rd-party package is suitable for python3.4. Is there a way I can test it?

I searched for pypi to get a version suitable for python3.4, but it turns out that this does not work well, as some 3rd-party-libs may rely on other packages with a semanticVersion mark `>=`.

Take `astroid==1.3.8` for an example. I googled and found this version satisfies 3.4.4, so I installed it, and found syntax error when I use `import astroid` in my python script. The error indicates a syntax error in the lib `logilab-common`.

```bash
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astroid\__init__.py",line 54, in <module>
   from astroid.nodes import *
......   // some traceback
......
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\logilab\common\deprecated.py", line 105
   self._proxied: Any = proxied
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It turns out that the package `astroid` requires `logilab-common>=0.63.0`, and when I use `pip install astroid==1.3.8`, it installed the latest `logilab-common`, which is `1.9.7`, and it used a type annotation, which caused this syntax error.

I managed to install `logilab-common==0.63.0`, and it worked fine when I use `import astroid`.

Does that mean I can use `astroid` all fine in python 3.4.4? I am not quite sure whether other functions or apis in this package will raise some syntax error or crash unexpectedly. Is there a way I can test it?

In the case, always installing the minium-satisfied-version of dependency-libs definitely works fine, but that's too much work for me. I want to find a way to test the utility of the libs and their dependency-libs.

Comment: you are going to find it hard to find packages compatible with less than 3.6

Comment: I understand many syntax changes has been made since 3.4. I am curious about whether it will work fine if `import xxx` works fine. Does that `import` part detects all the syntax errors?

Comment: it should detect syntax errors .... but there could be many other types of errors that might not be detected ...